# View document in browser whilst editing libray item properties

Tags: view, metadata, pdf

I am looking to be able to upload a PDF to a document library, and ask the user for mandatory field completion.

Once uploaded, a different user will need to look at the PDF and complete remaining fields about it.

Therefore, is it possible to open the PDF in the browser and display the edit properties fields so that the user can complete the properties whilst looking at the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB feature for this requirement. the best possible option would be to use a content editor webpart and embed the pdf document using the below custom script

```
<object><embed src="FILENAME.PDF" height="850" width="850"
type="application/pdf"></embed></object>
```

with in the edit form of the list/library.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm OK with getting a specific PDF to view on a page, but I am needing to display the file that is associated to the properties that are being edited.  So, when clicking on 'Edit Properties' the Edit Form opens as usual but with the associated document being shown with it.

Comment: then we should use a JSOM and dynamically build the pdf link associated with the list item and populate that.

Comment: Hello.  I don't know how to do that, can you provide any help as to how to?